# Is "EthArmbian" an OS for running Ethereum client on "micro-processors"?

Tags: blockchain, light-clients, clients, iot

Is "[EthArmbian](https://github.com/diglos/userpatches#etharmbian)" an `OS` for running `Ethereum light client` on "`micro-processors`" or "`micro-controllers`" ? And if yes, **which micro-processors** ?